# Upload multiple image (Alamofire)

Tags: swift, image, file-upload, upload, alamofire

I have a little problem.

I would like to send several images to my server with Alamofire but I have an error.. the proxy tell me : "Invalid request"

My code here :

```
func uploadImage(TabImage: [UIImage]){

    let urlReq = "http://www.myurl.com/upload.php"
    let parameters = ["id": my_id]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        var i=0
        for imageActuel in TabImage {
            let tmp_image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageActuel)
            let name = "exemple_"+ my_id +"_"+String(i)+"[]"
            let filename = "exemple_"+ my_id +"_"+String(i)+".jpg"
            multipartFormData.append(tmp_image_data!, withName: name,fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpg")
            i+=1
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    },to:urlReq)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value)
                if let dic = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{
                    print(dic)
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }


}
```

Do you see a problem in this function?

Thx for your help :)